# subscript out of bounds while implementing cross validation in r

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret

I am getting  ***Error in `[.default`(cm, 2, 2) : subscript out of bounds***  implementing cross-validation for xgboost. My dataset structure is as below:

```
'data.frame':   889 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Survived: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ Pclass  : int  3 1 3 1 3 3 1 3 3 2 ...
 $ Sex     : num  1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ SibSp   : int  1 1 0 1 0 0 0 3 0 1 ...
 $ Parch   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 ...
 $ Fare    : num  7.25 71.28 7.92 53.1 8.05 ...
 $ Embarked: num  3 1 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 1 ...
 - attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  Named int [1:2] 62 830
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "62" "830"
```

summary of my dataset is as below:

```
 Survived     Pclass           Sex            SibSp            Parch       
 0:549    Min.   :1.000   Min.   :1.000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000  
 1:340    1st Qu.:2.000   1st Qu.:1.000   1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0.0000  
          Median :3.000   Median :1.000   Median :0.0000   Median :0.0000  
          Mean   :2.312   Mean   :1.351   Mean   :0.5242   Mean   :0.3825  
          3rd Qu.:3.000   3rd Qu.:2.000   3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:0.0000  
          Max.   :3.000   Max.   :2.000   Max.   :8.0000   Max.   :6.0000  
      Fare            Embarked    
 Min.   :  0.000   Min.   :1.000  
 1st Qu.:  7.896   1st Qu.:2.000  
 Median : 14.454   Median :3.000  
 Mean   : 32.097   Mean   :2.535  
 3rd Qu.: 31.000   3rd Qu.:3.000  
 Max.   :512.329   Max.   :3.000
```

Error is thrown when implementing the below code:

```
library(caret)
folds = createFolds(traindataset$Survived, k = 10)
cv = lapply(folds, function(x) {
  training_fold = traindataset[-x, ]
  test_fold = traindataset[x, ]
  classifier = xgboost(data = as.matrix(traindataset[-1]), label = traindataset$Survived, nrounds = 10)
  y_pred = predict(classifier, newdata = as.matrix(test_fold[-1]))
  y_pred = (y_pred >= 0.5)
  cm = table(test_fold[, 1], y_pred)
  accuracy = (cm[1,1] + cm[2,2]) / (cm[1,1] + cm[2,2] + cm[1,2] + cm[2,1])
  return(accuracy)
})
```

Please note that I have converted ***Survived*** from an integer of 0 and 1 to a factor for classification purpose. To my surprise when Survived was an integer the code worked but when it is a factor I am getting that error.

Appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured a solution to the question. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Here me converting target variable into factor is creating the problem. I am assuming xgboost needs numerical inputs and not factors, hence creating the problem.